# lost point-tool-tips on line-chart (Chart.js) after redraw per ajax and destroying older line-chart graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, charts

I am drawing a line-chart with points and tooltips using chart.js, and to stop the flickering caused by Ajax, I am destroying my old line-chart and recreating it. However, my tooltips are now not working! I'm not sure what's causing this, and any help would be appreciated. You can find my code below.

This is my Ajax-Call - fired by changing the value of a Dropdown-Selection:

```
    var data;
    $('#KurveWatt').change(function(){
        var y = this.value;
        if(y == 'kW/Tag')
        {
            var urlajax = '/php/lineChartTag.php';              
        }
        else if(y == 'kW/Woche')
        {
            urlajax = '/php/lineChartWoche.php';                
        }
        else
        {               
            urlajax = '/php/lineChartStd.php';

        }
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: urlajax,
            success: function(data){                    
                updateChart(data.labels, data.points);  
                window.myLine.destroy();
                window.myChart.destroy();

            },              
        }); 

    });
```

And this is the function, that redraws the line-chart using new Ajax data:

```
    function updateChart(labels, points){               

        var canvas = $("#wattStd")[0].getContext("2d");     

        var data = {
                labels: labels,
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: "kW/Std. aktuell",
                        fillColor : "transparent",
                        strokeColor : "#ff9900",
                        pointColor : "#ff9900",
                        pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                        pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                        pointHighlightStroke : "#ff9900",
                        data: points 
                    }
                ]
            };

        myChart = new Chart(canvas)
                .Line(data, {
                responsive: true,
                animation: true
            });

    }
```

And the "original" line-Chart, which is shown up by entering the page:

```
    var lineChart = {
        labels : <?php echo $LClabel; ?>,
        datasets : [
                {
                    label: "kW/Std. aktuell",
                    fillColor : "transparent",
                    strokeColor : "#ff9900",
                    pointColor : "#ff9900",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "#ff9900",
                    data : <?php echo $LCdata; ?>
                }
            ]
        }
```

And now - at last - the sequence, that draws the line-chart:

```
    var wattStd = document.getElementById("wattStd").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(wattStd).Line(lineChart, {
        responsive: false
    });
```

THe HTML-Area "KurveWatt"

```
    <p class="headline">Verlaufsdiagramm Einspeisung nach <select id="KurveWatt" name="messwert">
                                                    <option class="kw" id="std" selected>kW/Std</option>
                                                    <option class="kw" id="tag">kW/Tag</option>
                                                    <option class="kw" id="woche">kW/Woche</option>
                                                    <option class="kw" id="monat">kW/Monat</option>
                                                    <option class="kw" id="jahr">kW/Jahr</option>
                                                </select></p>
```

And the HTML-Area  with the Canvas for the Line-Chart:

```
    <div class="kurveWatt" id="watt_std">
                <div>
                    <canvas id="wattStd" width="970" height="165"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't comment on your original question until I gain enough reputation, and as such I'm afraid I have to post an answer, but **please do not accept it as this is not a valid answer** However, I will attempt to help you.

I'm not sure what your issue is without seeing any code (or more informative description of your issue), however, I imagine it's something to do with the data for your tooltips. Ajax calls maybe? Or it could just be the data isn't rendered properly. If you could please comment with a read only git repo so as to allow me to help you (or edit your question to include the code snippets), that would be appreciated.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My deepest apologies, I just saw your edit, and I can't seem to delete my answer (issue on my end, I imagine). I will fix this at once.

Comment: Hi SyntaxBit,
yes - was my first question over here and it took a while to figure out, how this is working with adding a code-block... but as you can see - I made it :-)

Comment: Thank you @JoergZimmermann Would it also be possible to give me the HTML area with which you reference your JavaScript? (This appears to have an ID of 'KurveWatt'), and also the 'WattStd' element. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue your having here is a simple one to do with how you're accessing your elements.

HTML elements have two main identifiers, class and Id. Please see below for how these are defined

`div#KurveWatt` would then become this `<div id="KurveWatt"></div>`

and this `div.KurveWatt` would then become this `<div class="KurveWatt"></div>`

As such, # is Id, and . is class (this mostly only applies to JQuery DOM accessors). Please see below for a description of your issue.

As explained above, your Id's and Classes are mixed up. To access `<div id="KurveWatt"></div> in your JQuery, you would need`$('#KurveWatt')`. Also, for a better chart plugin, I suggest you visit [this site](http://visjs.org/graph2d_examples.html).

Other than that, I can't see any issues.

Hope this helps.